# Sharepoint Sequential Workflow not adding Task into Tasklist

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow

After the deployment of the workflow onto the sharepoint site, I am able to start the workflow by creating new rows of a list. These are also reflected in the field, "no. of workflow in progress". However, I cannot seem to find the tasks created for specific users in the Task list.

As a beginner with Sharepoint development, I am not exactly sure what is wrong. Please kindly advise.

Comment: More proper place for questions regarding SharePoint is http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Answer (score 0):

this is my tested code:

```
    private void OnCreateTask_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        taskId1 = Guid.NewGuid();
        //   SPContentTypeId myContentTypeId=new SPContentTypeId("0x01080100e73fd5f172cb40d8a5dca97fad7a58b8");
        SPContentType myContentType = SPContext.Current.Web.ContentTypes["Powerfull Approval Workflow Task"];
        CreateTaskApproval_ContentTypeID = myContentType.Id.ToString();
        #region Enable ContentTypes
        if (this.workflowProperties.TaskList.ContentTypesEnabled != true)
        {
            workflowProperties.TaskList.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
        }
        bool contenTypeExists = false;
        foreach (SPContentType contentType in workflowProperties.TaskList.ContentTypes)
        {
            if (contentType.Name == myContentType.Name)
            {
                contenTypeExists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (contenTypeExists != true)
        {
            workflowProperties.TaskList.ContentTypes.Add(myContentType);
        }
        myContentType.EditFormUrl = "_layouts/SequentialWorkflow/TaskEdit/TaskEditForm.aspx";
        myContentType.DisplayFormUrl = "_layouts/SequentialWorkflow/TaskEdit/TaskEditForm.aspx";
        myContentType.Update();
        #endregion
        taskProperties.PercentComplete = (float)0.0;
        taskProperties.AssignedTo = myInstantiationData.User;
        taskProperties.DueDate = myInstantiationData.DueDate;
        taskProperties.Description = myInstantiationData.Request;
        taskProperties.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        taskProperties.Title = "Please approve " + this.workflowProperties.Item.DisplayName;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks guys. It not a code issue. Its a properties setting issue. (: